# Is Postgres ignoring my function cost annotation?

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-9.2

Why does this:

```
create or replace function dummy() returns double precision as $$
SELECT random() $$
LANGUAGE SQL
COST 777;
explain select dummy();
```

return this:

```
Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
```

and not a cost of 777?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the costs refer to different units of measurement. The `cost` when used in functions is the estimated execution cost in units of [cpu_operator_cost](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CPU-OPERATOR-COST), whereas the `EXPLAIN` plan costs are units of disk page fetches ([seq_page_cost](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-SEQ-PAGE-COST)).

For function cost details, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

For `EXPLAIN` plan costs, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html